# how to use react-native-web and react-navigation together and access from web url

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-router-v4, react-native-web, react-router-native

**UPDATE**:

react-navigation web support is done. follow this:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html

**ORIGIN**:

I try to share my code between react-native and web.
when I try react-native-web, it works well.
but there is only one question, how to access the specific screen from URL?
I read the react-navigation docs, there nothing about that.
and react-router-native can catch the web URL, 
but it has navigator likes StackNavigator/DrawerNavigator.
and idea about that?

Comment: Could you share some code so we can see what we can work with?

Comment: and I dont really think this is completly possible (not sure if I interpreted your question correctly), Why do you have to use react-navigation at all? isn't navigatoin already included in your webpage in your `<WebView/>` component?

Comment: hi @joshkmartinez thanks for your reply. and, you can check this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-web

the official web support. 

and i am lazy is why i want to use react-navigation at all.

Comment: Oh... so you developed and a react-native-app and want to use it on the web?

Comment: yep, native app is big, some time just a PWA is done.

Comment: Is there a way you could add the code? Is it in a git repo?

Comment: please note, react-native-web team thinks react-navigation v3 is still not ready: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1224#issuecomment-453183833 (that was 2 weeks ago)

Comment: @robertotomás yes, i think the navigation-web is just in beta, and i still in v2, and i write a root browser url detect component, when something change it will route to right navigation. that is. hope the react-navigation team can implement for web next day.

Comment: Hi GeminiYellow, I have the same issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: @vannguyen no... i using react-router now.

Comment: @GeminiYellow, you convert all react-navigation code to react-router?

Comment: yep, and i notice that they start a web version, https://github.com/react-navigation/web, but the road is too far.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the case was at the time you posted this question, but you definitely can use react-navigation with web now adays.

Now with Linking we can Handle deep links in React Native apps on Android and iOS, plus
Enable URL integration in browser when using on web.

The `NavigationContainer` component takes in a linking prop which allows you to map out your routes.

```js
    const linking = {
      prefixes: ['https://mychat.com', 'mychat://'],
      config: {
        screens: {
          Chat: 'feed/:sort',
          Profile: 'user',
        },
      },
    };


    function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
          {/* content */}
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

Once we establish what all of the routes or "links" are in our app we can start using `Link` components to navigate just like in a normal react web application if you used react-router-dom.

```js
   import { Link } from '@react-navigation/native';

// ...

   function Home() {
     return <Link to="/profile/jane">Go to Jane's profile</Link>;
   }
```

These link components should work on both mobile, and web versions.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/link

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible as ReactNavigation is using an internal state object. Remember, it's mobile framework, it has no concept of URL routing.
I also wanted to point out that even though RN claims web support you will need to be careful with component selection as not all the behaviours are identical (from memory, FlatList does not support touch scroll)