# Accessing URL with params from a react-native-web app

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I am working on a React-Native app which I have ported it to Web using React-Native-Web (hosted on say http://myapp.com).

What I would like to do now, is to make custom URLs, like `http://myapp.com/some/path/here/with/?params=something` which I can access it in my app to dispatch appropriate navigation action after parsing it.

My question is, how do I access `/some/path/here/maybe/with/?params=something`?

With webpack dev server, whenever I try to access say `localhost:8080/asdf`, it gives an error `Cannot GET /asdf`

I am using react-navigation 3.3.2 (with web compatibility [patch](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1224#issuecomment-460604999) for gesture handler). I have visited this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186634/how-to-use-react-native-web-and-react-navigation-together-and-access-from-web-ur) but it talks about a tightly coupled mapping from link to screen.

What I want is something rather simple, I only need the path somewhere in my react app, so that I can act on it in some way.

Answer (score 2):

An exemple from my use case :
In navigation

```
    export default createApp(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        HomeScreen : {screen: HomeScreen, path: ''},
        Contact : {screen: Contact, path: 'Contact'},
        EmailVerification : {screen : EmailVerification, path: 'confirm_email/:uid'},//<- this is how to access the page on yousite.com/confirmMail/parameterValueWithoutAnyQuestionMark
    },{
        initialRouteName:'HomeScreen',
    })
);
```

In your page file :

```
class EmailVerification extends Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            isProcessDone : false, 
            uid : this.props.navigation.getParam('uid') //<- this uid paramName must be the same as in navigation
        };
    }
}
```

This is how I do it in my app, it might change based on your navigation I guess.